# Can we use bounded convergence theorem to calculate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{n \sin(x)}{1 + n^2 \sqrt{x}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I know how to use dominated convergence theorem to calculate  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{n \sin(x)}{1 + n^2 \sqrt{x}}$? Can we use bounded convergence theorem to calculate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{n \sin(x)}{1 + n^2 \sqrt{x}}$?

The bounded convergence theorem statement is as follows:

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions on a set of finite measure $E.$ Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly pointwise bounded on $E,$ that is, there is a number $M \geq 0$ for which $$|f_n| \leq M $$ on $E$ for all $n.$

If $\{f_n\} \rightarrow f$ pointwise on $E,$ then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_E f_n = \int_E f.$

Could anyone help me in this please?

Comment: $ \sin x <x$ and $\frac {nx} {1+n^{2}\sqrt x} \leq \frac 1  2$.

Comment: So you are saying yes we can @KaviRamaMurthy am I correct?

Comment: Yes, we can use Bounded ConvergenceTheorem